# How to paste Excel Chart as bitmap in email with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, win32com

Trying to copy and paste an excel chart into the body of an email. My first step was to try to save it as an image, and then copy and paste the image into an email. However i am getting this error when trying to save it: `com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'That name is already taken. Try a different one.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)`

If anybody knew a better solution to copy and paste excel charts into email, let me know! I already have an emailer that works. I am just trying to save the chart.

My Code is:

```
def capture_image(workbook,worksheet_name,name_of_image,t=5):

        
    xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
    time.sleep(t)
    wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(workbook,None,False)
    xlapp.Visible = False
    xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.RefreshAll()
    time.sleep(t*2)

    #To select particular worksheet of the workbook by name.
    xlapp.Sheets(worksheet_name).Select()

    # To create an object for the worksheet.
    xlSheet1 = xlapp.Sheets(worksheet_name)

    i =0
    # "chart" will capture all the charts available in the seleted worksheet.
    for chart in xlSheet1.ChartObjects():
        print (chart.Name)
        chart.CopyPicture()

        #Create new temporary sheet
        xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After=xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3)).Name="temp_sheet" + str(i)

        # To create an object for the worksheet.
        temp_sheet = xlapp.ActiveSheet

        #Add chart object to new sheet.
        cht = xlapp.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects().Add(0,0,800, 600)

        #Paste copied chart into new object
        cht.Chart.Paste()

        #Export image
        #cht.Chart.Export("chart" + str(i) + ".png")

    #Provide a range in which the image need to be copied from the temporary worksheet.
    temp_sheet.Range(temp_sheet.Cells(1,1),temp_sheet.Cells(1,1)).CopyPicture()

    #It will capture copied image from the clipboard and assign that to img variable.
    img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
    if img is None:
       print('Error: No image data in clipboard')

    #we will provide address and name to which the immage need to be saved.
    imgFile = os.path.join('G:\\MyFolder\\',name_of_image)
    img.save(imgFile)

    #Delete the temporary worksheet when chart image is capture.
    temp_sheet.Delete()
    wb.Save()
    wb.Close()
    xlapp.Quit()

workbook = 'C:\\Users\\myFolder\\myData.xlsx'
worksheet_name = 'GRAPH'
name_of_image = 'MyImage'
a = capture_image(workbook, worksheet_name, name_of_image)
```

Comment: May not be an issue, but you are not incrementing the loop counter,`i`. Once you have added the new sheet with `Add()` you are trying to give it the same `Name` as a sheet that already exists. That is likely the error you are seeing.

Comment: A general comment is that using the clipboard is usually a last resort. Better to loop over the chart objects, export them to file (as you are doing), then attach the files to the email. You do not say, but are you using Outlook as your email client?